# Concat column values in a dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, concatenation, databricks

I have a csv file that looks like the following

```
name, state, a, b, c, d, ..., x
Jon,  NY,    1, 4, 6, 2,      6
Eric, CA,    5, 3, 1, 5,      6
Chris,LA,    4, 4, 3, 1,      5
```

and I want the following result (one column with concat fields (inkl header name))

```
concate-fields
"name=Jon,   state=NY, a=1, b=4, c=6, d= 2, ... x=6"
"name=Eric,  state=CA, a=5, b=3, c=1, d= 5, ... x=6"
"name=Chris, state=LA, a=4, b=4, c=3, d= 1, ... x=5"
```

There can be many headers from a...>x so these should be appended in a generic way

I now have

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{concat, lit}
val lp = sample.select(concat(lit("name), $"name", lit(",state="), $"state")
display(lp)
```

But I have trouble adding the same for column a->x (as this needs to be done in a generic way)

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create SQL expression to concat columns by calling `map` method on `df.columns()` as shown below.

```
val df = // Read CSV

df.withColumn("concate-fields", expr(s"concat(${df.columns.map(col=>s"'$col=', nvl($col,'null'),','").mkString("").dropRight(4)})"))
    .withColumn("concate-fields", concat(lit("\""),col("concate-fields"),lit("\"")))
```

Comment: This works! How can I deal with null values (some of the rows have null values and this results in concate-fields also being null (if one cell is null the entire concate-fields is null)

Comment: You can use `nvl`or `coalesce` function. Updated the answer.